# Using list to iterate over dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list 'labels' and a dictionary with key, value pairs 'class_dict'.

I want to loop over my labels list, and print the dictionary key (e.g. 'airplane'), if the class_dict.value() is equal to the label[i].

```
labels = [2, 7, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 5, 1, 6, 3, 4, 2, 9, 3, 8]

class_dict ={'airplane': 0, 'automobile': 1, 'bird': 2,'cat': 3,'deer': 4,'dog': 5,'frog': 6, 'horse': 7,'ship': 8,'truck': 9}
```

For example

```
labels[0] = 'bird'
labels[1] = 'ship'
labels[2] = 'automobile'
```

Essentially I want to do this but in a more concise way:

```
for i in labels:
  for key, val in classes_dict.items():
    if val == i:
      print(key)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right. If you would like a nudge getting started, I might create a new dictionary that swapped the keys and values of `class_dict`

Comment: Are the values always sequential and unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could for example swap key and value of the dict and then simply access it with the list elements:

```
reversed_dict = {value: key for key, value in class_dict.items()}
new_list = [reversed_dict[x] for x in labels]

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['bird', 'horse', 'automobile', 'airplane', 'cat', 'bird', 'airplane', 'dog', 'automobile', 'frog', 'cat', 'deer', 'bird', 'truck', 'cat', 'ship']
```

Comment: This assumes there arent any duplicate values

Comment: Yes, you are both right!

Answer (score 1):

please note that your dictionnary is reversed, so think about reverse it first

```
labels = [2, 7, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 5, 1, 6, 3, 4, 2, 9, 3, 8]
class_dict ={'airplane': 0, 'automobile': 1, 'bird': 2,'cat': 3,'deer': 4,'dog': 5,'frog': 6, 'horse': 7,'ship': 8,'truck': 9}
new_dict = {v: k for k, v in class_dict.items()}

for l in labels:
    print(new_dict[l])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are always sequential starting from 0 and increasing you can just get the keys and do a normal look up

```
class_keys = class_dict.keys()
labels = [class_keys[i] for i in labels]
```